# Error when trying to calculate mean for a series column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the mean of a column which contains a lists/series but get an error while doing so. The example dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[1,2,3]]})
df ['a'].mean()
```

The error as follows:

```
Could not convert [1, 2, 3] to numeric.
```

Not sure why this happens and how to fix it. Can someone please help? thanks

Comment: You bave a list, use `df['a'].apply(np.mean)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your cell value type is `list` we need `apply`

```
df.a.apply(np.mean)
0    2.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! And how can I convert and store it as a list i.e. [1,2,3]. `list(df['a'])` seems to add extra `[]` whereas just assigning it to a list with `mylist = df['a']` converts `mylist` to a series.